# PHP Array [$var] not working

Tags: php, arrays, variables

i have a simple Array and i want to call them by an $variable.

example:

```
$test = array(01=>"Januar",
              02=>"Februar",
              03=>"M&auml;rz",
              04=>"April",
              05=>"Mai",
              06=>"Juni",
              07=>"Juli",
              08=>"August",
              09=>"September",
              10=>"Oktober",
              11=>"November",
              12=>"Dezember");

$monat = strftime("%m",$timestamp);
```

So in $monat is something like "04" ... then i call my array:

```
echo $test[$monat];
```

But nothing happens ... i did not understand why ... when i call

```
echo $monat;
```

shows me "04", "03" ...

why didnt give me the array something?

Comment: wrap your keys in quotes `'01' => ...` as `(int)01 == 1`

Comment: When you say "nothing happens", do you mean that you get neither the array value nor an `undefined index` notice? Have you configured PHP to display all error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your array a little more basic, like so:

```
$test = array('January', 'February', 'March');
```

Then just add or subtract 1  depending which way you go.

ASGM has the right idea, except I would go the other way:

```
$test = array("January" => "04");
```

which can be easier to work with ... all really situational and preferential

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that `strftime("%m",$timestamp);` returns a string (hence the `str` in `strftime`), while the keys in your array are all numbers.

If you change the keys in your arrays to be strings, then it should work:

```
$test = array("01"=>"Januar",
              "02"=>"Februar",
              "03"=>"M&auml;rz",
              "04"=>"April",
...
```

Comment: but strftime("%m",$timestamp); returns me 04 ... so thats equal in my array?

Comment: Check the type of the returned value; it should be a string.  Otherwise the leading zero wouldn't display.  If you make the keys in your array strings too, then they'll match.  Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @user2192028 - If you configure your system to display error messages, PHP will tell you about these problems automatically. You'll no longer have to guess!

Comment: @all could also point out for completeness - casting `$monat` as integer would be a reasonable alternative too... [example](http://codepad.org/Ia4vTMPl)